# Google oauth2 works fine in localhost but not works in domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-signin

I am trying to integrated Google Calendar Integration to my web site. Everything run on local host is perfect. But when I publish it in to domain it give me some error.

> This bt.mypage.kr page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web
> address:
> http://bt.mypage.kr/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events&access_type=online&include_granted_scopes=true&response_type=code&state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&redirect_uri=http://bt.mypage.kr/Schedule/UI/oauth2callback&client_id=myclientid

My code some thing like this:

```
public ActionResult AuthRedirect()
        {
            var url = "http://" + Request.Host;
            sting redirect_uri = url + "/Schedule/UI/oauth2callback"
            GoogleParram gpr = new GoogleParram(url);

            string rerectUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?" +
 "scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events&" +
 "access_type=online&" +
 "include_granted_scopes=true&" +
 "response_type=code&" +
 "state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&" +
 "redirect_uri=" + url + "/Schedule/UI/oauth2callback&" +
 "client_id=" + gpr.client_id;
            return Redirect(rerectUrl);
        }

        public void oauth2callback(string code, string error, string state)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error))
            {
                this.GetTokens(code);
            }
        }

        public IActionResult GetTokens(string code)
        {

            var url = "http://" + Request.Host;
            
            GoogleParram gpr = new GoogleParram(url);

            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.AddQueryParameter("client_id", gpr.client_id);
            request.AddQueryParameter("client_secret", gpr.client_secret);
            request.AddQueryParameter("code", code);
            request.AddQueryParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
            request.AddQueryParameter("redirect_uri", url + "/Schedule/UI/oauth2callback&");

            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(gpr.token_uri);
            var response = restClient.Post(request);

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                gpr.WriteToken(response.Content);
                return RedirectToAction("Calendar");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Calendar");
        }
```

My Credentials

[image]

I hope anybody knows how to solve. Bundle of Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use the google apis .net client library?

Comment: whats the full error message you are getting?  btw redirect uris really should be https not http.

Comment: @DalmTo On apis .net client library it has the same error

Comment: Your not using the .net client library from what i can see you are trying to reinvent the wheel.   This error has nothing to do with google authorization your trying to reach a web page on your site **http:// bt.mypage.kr/o/oauth2/v2/auth**  which does not exist. Fix your code so that you redirect to a page you have on your site.